# Unity3D: ¿Cómo limitar el spawn de enemigos?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estoy haciendo un FPS de supervivencia en Unity3D, y no sé cómo limitar el spawn de los enemigos por ronda. Esta es la parte del código que verifica que, si la cantidad de enemigos en ronda es menor al total (10), instancia a los enemigos, pero si la cantidad de enemigos en ronda es 0, para el spawner, actualiza la UI en 1, se produce el sonido de cambio de ronda  y el spawn tiene que esperar 7 minutos para volver a iniciarse.

```
if (EnemiesInRound < maxEnemies)
{
   stopSpawner = false;
}
else if (EnemiesInRound == 0)
{
   stopSpawner = true;
   round.text = " " + 1;
   pass.Play();
   WaitForNextWave = 7f;
}
```

Muchas gracas por la ayuda.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, quieres limitar el numero de enemigos o controlar que pasen los 7 min?

Comment: Quiero limitar el spawn de los enemigos y que, al terminar la ronda, pasen 7 minutos para que se spawneen los de la segunda, y así sucesivamente.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que podrías utilizar una coroutine.

```
if (EnemiesInRound < maxEnemies)
{
   stopSpawner = false;
}
else if (EnemiesInRound == 0)
{
   stopSpawner = true;
   round.text = " " + 1;
   pass.Play();
   StartCoroutine(WaitForNextWave(tiempo));
}

IEnumerator WaitForNextWave(float t)
{
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(t);
   //Código a ejecutar después del tiempo de espera.
}
```

Comment: La coroutine ya la hice, yo me refería a ctualizar la UI cuando termina la ronda

Comment: Si quieres actualizar la UI simplemente tendrías que hacer un if(stopSpawner) en el método Update(). Para que si stopSpawner es igual a true, entre y actualice la UI.

Comment: No actualiza la UI

Comment: Cuando suceda lo que dice @VickyVicent, para actualizar la UI, podrías hacer:

round.text = " " + (Convert.ToInt32(rount.text) + 1);

Comment: La UI sigue sin actualizar incluso con el if(spawner) y el Convert.ToInt32